# Can I use Google Cardboard as a normal display?

Tags: screen, google-cardboard

Can I write a message using Google Cardboard?

Or, can I use Cardboard as I use the phone's display?

Or, can I get normal text displayed in Cardboard?

What I am looking for is the possibility to have the equivalent of a 20" display that can fit in my pocket.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: What is the exact question? Do you want to use Google Cardboard without the 3D effect (i.e. to hold your phone at a set position in front of your face)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I do not need anything special to use my phone display as a classic huge display.
The only requirements are:

- A high resolution display (2560x1440 in my case).
- Keep the phone at 10 centimeters from my eyes.

If you are short-sighted (my case), you need nothing else. If you are not, you will need a pair of glasses to allow to focus the text without straining your crystalline lenses.

Comment: This is not an answer, rather, a clarification to the question. Please edit the question to include this information.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos: I wrote it as an answer because I got to that conclusion at a later stage. If I put it in the question, it would not be a question anymore, but an assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're asking if you can do normal phone functions i.e. text, email using Google Cardboard. Cardboard is for demonstrating Virtual Reality, and only apps written for cardboard will display normally in cardboard. If a developer decides to write a Virtual Reality texting app, then yes, you could "write a message using Google Cardboard". However, that really defeats the purpose of virtual reality.

You are unable to interact with the phone screen normally when it's inside the Cardboard goggles.

Cardboard does indeed display normal text. It uses your phone display, so I'm not quite sure what "Can I use Google Cardboard as a normal display?" is supposed to mean.

Have you used cardboard? Do you know what it does? From your questions, I get the feeling you're not really sure.

Comment: I have never used Cardboard. What I am hoping to be able to do is to use it as a huge display to write text/code/diagrams/browse the web. So all I would need is Android to show what it normally shows, but twice on each half of the display. I do not need a stereoscopic view, 3D, ... or other computationally intensive features. All I need is Android to resize the output to half the width, and show it twice side by side.

Comment: So basically you want multiwindow?

Comment: Also, you won't get a "huge display", it'll be about the size of your screen.

Comment: It should just be an exact copy of the same view. The display would look huge because it would be at a few centimeters from the eyes (with lenses to adjust focus).

Comment: Oh I think I kind of understand what you're getting at now. Cardboard definitely doesn't add this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

1# - Google Cardboard only holds your smartphone screen over your eyes, nothing else.
2# - Google Cardboard has lenses which magnify the display, might help.
3# - Generally most smartphone displays over 1080p will become retina around 6 inches. Retina means that after that point you will be able to see pixels. 
4# - Unless you have a 1440p or higher phone, 10 centimeters won't cut it (4 inches). You will be able to see the pixels. 
5# - In order you use the Cardboard, your phone display needs to be at least 5 inches.

So use these ideas you help you, and I recommend the LG G3 for this.

Overall use these steps to help you,

Comment: Google Cardboard has two lenses one of which focuses on the left half of the display, the other on the right half. So I suppose that you cannot use it to read normal text or view normal images, but it is specifically tailored for stereoscopic vision.